# How display debug messages from antcall?

Tags: java, ant, echo

My project uses ant, I would like to check parameters that inside antcall, but antcall doesn't permit use . How I can see parameters?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `<echo>` the values you're passing to `<antcall>` inside the `<target>` containing the `<antcall>`, or echo them within the called target.